# How to download a file from a URL returned by an API in React?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a front end that lists documents, when a user clicks to download it will call the API and request a URL with a Amazon Storage SAS token. This happens async, so may take a short moment. Once the URL is returned how can I then trigger the download?

I cant pre fetch the URL as it has a SAS token that expires after a period of time, the user may easily wait past that period of time before fetching the document and would get a access denied error.

I cant use a anchor tag as the URL is not known at the time of click. I could create a new button that says download, but now the user presses download twice, for one file. Is there a way to trigger a download? Perhaps in useEffect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  async donwloadWookLog(id) {
    const blob = await this.workLogService.getWorklog(id)
    .catch(error => {
      this.notify.showMessage('Unable to download work log.', 2000);
    });

    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = 'work_log_' + id+' .xlsx';
    link.click();

    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
```

TS code sample